# PL/SQL query via VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, plsql, ado, adodb

I am trying to pass PL/SQL query from file via VBA to the Oracle DB.

Simple test query like `SELECT * FROM DUAL` 
works flawlessly.

However just a bit more complicated (even not yet PL/SQL) like

`SELECT x, y, z FROM table WHERE DATE = '5may2017'`

already fails (actually no explicit error, just empty result).

I'm connecting to `Conn.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle.1"`, apply user schema by `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=MyUserSchema`. Finally my last code-snippet is:

```
With Cmd
    .Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True '(actually this line doesnt affect)'
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = SqlStatement
    Set rs = .Execute
End With

Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

So, excel sheet is populated with the 1st test simpliest query, however remains empty for the more complex part (I have no semicolon in the end :) )
However final sql-script will be 400+ lines long...

What am I missing at this step?

Comment: PS. I don't have any procedures in the DB, and the access is ReadOnly, so I'm not able to run PL/SQL from procedures

Comment: PLease show the table definition.  No data is not a failure.

Comment: Quick look, if you are not getting an error and are getting an empty result set, that probably means the query worked and found nothing that met your specifications. Possibly you have no records with that date, or you specified the date in a format that it did not recognize. What happens if you run it without the WHERE clause?

Comment: For Toad users, check your NLS SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;
; your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is not default one DD-MON-RR.

Comment: I think it must be `Set rs = .Open` instead of `Set rs = .Execute`

Comment: @philippeko thanks for advise, this was new to me. However, I have exactly DD-MON-RR NLS_DATE_FORMAT as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try instead **ANSI Date** 'YYYY-MM-DD' or **ANSI Time** 'HH:MM:SS' **SQL formatting** below for an implicit conversion with SQL ANSI DATE or SQL ANSI TIME operator.

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM table WHERE COLUMN_DATE = DATE '2017-05-05'
SELECT x, y, z FROM table WHERE COLUMN_TIME = TIME '23:59:59'
- according such "COL_" exists
```

A must-keep cheatsheet for quick reference [PSOUG Datatypes](http://psoug.org/reference/datatypes.html)

NB: For Toad users, check your NLS `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;`
; your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is not default one `DD-MON-RR`.

Comment: Must-read Oracle ressources [Working with Dates in PL/SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12plsql-1408561.html) by Steven Feuerstein

Comment: Thanks, this helped indeed. Still strange for me as '5may2017' works in TOAD

Comment: That most likely is due to TOAD not being just passive. It has an internal date setting and may have noticed the date format and either issued an alter session or modified the query to specify the format.